# C# matrix search algorithm

Tags: c#, arraylist

I'm currently stuck at a problem where I need to search through a matrix and return a new list containing all the elements in a "circle" around a set coordinate in the matrix.

That probably didn't make too much sense so I'll try and explain some more.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw7XA.png)

Seen here in matrix[4, 5] is the red tile. In other words the coordinate chosen for this example.
Shown by the green tiles those are the ones that I am wanting to aim to add to a newly created list to be returned at the end of this function.

The function will take a tuple of the coordinates of the "middle" tile (seen as the red one) as the parameter.

I am looking for the size of this "circle" to be able to be changed by a variable of the "radius" as shown by the pink arrow in the image example it is 3.

One of the most important details is for the algorithm to be robust to any out of range errors from getting the tile that may not be in the matrix.

I have been trying to figure out my own solution for quite sometime but came to no luck anyone with any ideas please try and explain in details and maybe with examples.

Hope this made sense. Thanks!

Comment: You don't show any code! What is your question? This is a question and answer site, where you ask questions about your code and we answer any questions you have about your code. To do this problem, there is no search involved. You get the circle's center and radius, and using basic trigonometry and an appropriate rounding function, you figure which coordinates are within the circle (and which ones aren't)

Comment: @Flydog57 The reason I didn’t mention any code is because I didn’t really have any reasonable code due to not knowing where to start with this. I was looking for an algorithm or an explanation on how to do this. Would you mind further expanding on your trigonometry approach, maybe some equations? Thanks.

Comment: One of the nice things about circles and trigonometry is that you only need to do the calculations for 1/8 or 1/4 of the circle (aka 45 deg) - which ever is easier. Start at the center and work in one direction using the x2+y2 < r2 formula to decide if it should be included. Once you get one chunk done, you can manipulate the signs and the x & y order to get the rest

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (didn't checked):

```
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> GetDiamondSquareIndexes(Tuple<int, int> centerPosition, int radius)
    {
        if (radius <= 0)
        {
            yield return centerPosition;
            yield break;
        }

        var diameter = (radius << 1) + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < diameter; i++)
        {
            var offset = Math.Abs(i - radius);
            var count = diameter - (offset << 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            {
                yield return Tuple.Create(i + centerPosition.Item1 - radius, j + offset + centerPosition.Item2 - radius);
            }
        }
    }
```

Idea behind is to run through each row (from top to bottom), find offset for this row and count of green squares for this row, then you just enumerate them (from [offset] edge to [offset+count] edge).

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the problem into the points first and then add a bounds check later:

```
public static IEnumerable<Point> GetManhattanCircle(Point center, int radius)
{
    return DiamondPoints().Where(InBounds);

    IEnumerable<Point> DiamondPoints()
    {
        for (var dy = -radius; dy <= radius; dy++)
            for (var dx = -radius; dx <= radius; dx++)
                if (Math.Abs(dx) + Math.Abs(dy) <= radius)
                    yield return new Point(center.X + dx, center.Y + dy);
    }
}
```

The code would be even better if you have a helper function for the Manhattan distance as then you could really write

```
if(p.ManhattenDistanceTo(center) <= radius)
```

so signify that this is really a circle in the Manhattan distance metric.